# Save TouchListView and open it next time when app opens

Tags: android, listview, commonsware-cwac

I need help how do I save my ListView's order after drag and drop. My list have items (google and yahoo) and when user press them it opens www.google.com or www.yahoo.com.

So right now every time I reorder my listview and close the app it forgot that order which I made earlier and opens deault order.

**My code:**

```
    private static String[] items={
        "Google",
                "Yahoo"};

    private static String[] links={
        "http://google.com",
                "http://yahoo.com};

    private IconicAdapter adapter=null;

    private IconicAdapter1 adapter2=null;

    ArrayList<String> array= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));

    private ArrayList<String> array2=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(links));


    /** Called when the activity is first created. **/
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        TouchListView tlv=(TouchListView)getListView();
        adapter=new IconicAdapter();
        adapter2=new IconicAdapter1();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        setListAdapter(adapter2);

        tlv.setOnItemClickListener(itemclick);
        tlv.setDropListener(onDrop);

   }



        private TouchListView.DropListener onDrop=new TouchListView.DropListener() {
            @Override
            public void drop(int from, int to) {
                    String item=(String) adapter.getItem(from);

                    adapter.remove(item);
                    adapter.insert(item, to);

                    String link=(String) adapter2.getItem(from);
                    adapter2.remove(link);
                    adapter2.insert(link, to);


            }
        };

        private TouchListView.OnItemClickListener itemclick= new TouchListView.OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int from, long id) {

                String item = adapter.getItem(from);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "you pick: "+item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String link = adapter2.getItem(from);
                Intent showContent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Web.class);
                showContent.setData(Uri.parse(link));
                startActivity(showContent);
            }
        };

        class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
            IconicAdapter() {
                super(MainScreen.this, R.layout.row, array);
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                                                    ViewGroup parent) {
                View row=convertView;

                    if (row==null) {                                                    
                    LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();

                    row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
                }

                TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);

                label.setText(array.get(position));

                return(row);

            }
        };

            class IconicAdapter1 extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
                IconicAdapter1() {
                    super(MainScreen.this, R.layout.row, array2);
                }

                public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                                                        ViewGroup parent) {
                    View row=convertView;

                    if (row==null) {                                                    
                        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();

                        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
                    }

                    TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);

                    label.setText(array.get(position));

                    return(row);

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're concerned with storing the state of items in a list, how about storing your data in a [SQLite database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) and using a [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html)? you can store your order as a column in the db.

In general though, you'll need to take care of saving your Application state explicitly. Have a look here for more details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I don't know how to use CursorAdapter with drag and drop ListView :/

Comment: I can't get that CursorAdapter works. So do you have any ideas or any tutorials how do I can save my arraylists and then get them back? :)